# Convert php array to select box options

Tags: php, arrays, categories

I have an input category array with childs  as follows

I want to convert it using a recursive function to another array like

### OUTPUT NEEDED

['1'=>'fashion', '10' => 'fashion > women','23'=> 'fashion > women > clothing','29'=> 'fashion > women > clothing > dresses' ... and so on ]

My purpose is to use output array to populate select box  options to adda category.

### INPUT ARRAY

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => fashion
            [parent_id] => 0
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [name] => women
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [childs] => Array
                                (
                                    [23] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 23
                                            [name] => clothing
                                            [parent_id] => 10
                                            [childs] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [29] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 29
                                                            [name] => dresses
                                                            [parent_id] => 23
                                                            [childs] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

```
                                                    )

                                                [30] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 30
                                                        [name] => jumpsuits
                                                        [parent_id] => 23
                                                        [childs] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [24] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 24
                                        [name] => bags & accessories
                                        [parent_id] => 10
                                        [childs] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [25] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 25
                                        [name] => shoes
                                        [parent_id] => 10
                                        [childs] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [26] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 26
                                        [name] => watches
                                        [parent_id] => 10
                                        [childs] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [27] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 27
                                        [name] => jewelery
                                        [parent_id] => 10
                                        [childs] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [28] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 28
                                        [name] => eye-wear
                                        [parent_id] => 10
                                        [childs] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 11
                        [name] => men
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 12
                        [name] => kids
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 13
                        [name] => sports
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14
                        [name] => bags
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [15] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 15
                        [name] => eyewear
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 16
                        [name] => watches & jewelery
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => supermarket
        [parent_id] => 0
        [childs] => Array
            (
                [17] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 17
                        [name] => food & beverages
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                                [31] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 31
                                        [name] => breakfast
                                        [parent_id] => 17
                                        [childs] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [32] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 32
                                        [name] => snacks
                                        [parent_id] => 17
                                        [childs] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [18] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 18
                        [name] => dairy products
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [19] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 19
                        [name] => beauty
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [20] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 20
                        [name] => homecare
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [21] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 21
                        [name] => baby world
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [22] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 22
                        [name] => pet world
                        [parent_id] => 2
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => electronics
        [parent_id] => 0
        [childs] => Array
            (
                [33] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 33
                        [name] => laptops
                        [parent_id] => 3
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [34] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 34
                        [name] => television
                        [parent_id] => 3
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => mobiles & tablets
        [parent_id] => 0
        [childs] => Array
            (
                [35] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 35
                        [name] => mobiles
                        [parent_id] => 4
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [36] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 36
                        [name] => tablets
                        [parent_id] => 4
                        [childs] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => baby & toys
        [parent_id] => 0
        [childs] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => home
        [parent_id] => 0
        [childs] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [name] => perfumes & beauty
        [parent_id] => 0
        [childs] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [name] => sports & fitness
        [parent_id] => 0
        [childs] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [name] => automotive
        [parent_id] => 0
        [childs] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

)

I need an output array with key,the category id

Comment: can you explain more .

Comment: Please give output what you want .

Answer (score 0):

You can create array by this way:

```
$array = array(
 'category_1' => 'value',
 'category_2' => array(
                  'subcategory_1' => 'value',
                  'subcategory_2' => 'value',
                 ),
);
```

Comment: It's not a ans .